# Browser history doubled in angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, iframe, browser-history

So I am using a web app which has an iframe pointing to my angularjs application. If I navigate around the parent web app, I notice that the browser history is doubled up. For example, if I navigate to `contacts > about us > home`, then the history will be:

```
- home
- about us
- about us
- contacts
- contacts
```

If I point the iframe to a simple web page with no angular, then the parent app history works fine. I came across this bug on the angularjs website with a similar issue which appears to have been resolved in an earlier version of angular: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1054 but it doesn't seem to be resolved for some people. I'm using v1.2.26. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: So I've narrowed the issue down somewhat by removing everything from the iframe app except the basic building blocks (i.e. kept all angular library/dependencies, app controllers/services/directives, etc and only removed the ng-view directive). As such, the browser history works fine. However when I re-introduce the ng-view directive, that's when the history starts to double-up. Perhaps something to do ngRoute navigation?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out my assumptions about routing as the potential cause were correct, and I can't believe I didn't realize this sooner. Essentially my iframe app routes to different locations through some sort of event. Each route, while it does not impact the parent url, will add a new entry to the browser history (which is normal browser behaviour). The iframe app is designed upon page load to run through a couple routes, thus adding to the browser history, and making it appear like each parent page navigation was doubled.

The question now becomes, is there a way to prevent each route execution from adding the browser history?

**UPDATE:**
`$location.replace()` seems to be the only solution I can find. The app makes use of `$location.path()` a lot to trigger a new route; so I've modified it to be `$location.path().replace();` This will replace the current history entry instead of adding a new one.